# How to get a float parsed value from db?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a float value from a mysql database which is formated this way `0,5`. Selecting it, I get back `0` as response. How do I please to get the float value ?

I'm selecting it this way:

```
    $requete = $this->bdd->bd->prepare('SELECT charge 
                                        FROM detailsfiche 
                                        WHERE ref_hl = :ref_hl 
                                         && intervenant = :intervenant');
    $requete->bindValue(':ref_hl', $refhl, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $requete->bindValue(':intervenant', $intervenant, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $requete->execute();
    $data = $requete->fetch();
    $requete->CloseCursor();
    return $data['charge'];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it really in the format `0,5`? or did you mean `0.5`? also have you tried `SELECT CAST(charge AS DECIMAL) as charge FROM...` ?? --- or this? `SELECT ROUND(charge, 2) as charge FROM...`

Comment: @JohnRuddell, thanks for response but that is sending back an error message : `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CAST(charge AS DECIMAL) FROM detailsfiche WHERE ref_hl = '72817' && inter' at line 1`.

Comment: so its storing a decimal/float with a comma between the numbers instead of a period?

Comment: What's the actual datatype of `charge` column? Post your table structure.

Comment: @JohnRuddell, yes, I've just checked the datatype of `charge` column it's varchar. But, how do I to parse that to a float number ? Maybe replacing its comma with one dot and parsing it ?

Comment: @JohnRuddell, OP says `charge` is a float type. if that's the case then `0,5` must be the size specification which is not possible. Cause if you try to add the column like `charge float(0,5)` it will throw an error saying `float(m,d) .. m > d`

Comment: If it's varchar then you should get it as-is.

Comment: @Rahul, I'm making on that output some addition operations.

Comment: Make your post clear. Add all information to avoid confusion. else you will end up closing the question as "unclear"

Answer (score 1):

per comment your `charge` field is `varchar` which has values like `0,5`. In that case, you can use `REPLACE()` function to replace the `,` with `.` like

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(charge,',','.') AS float(5,3)) FROM detailsfiche 
WHERE ref_hl = :ref_hl 
AND intervenant = :intervenant
```

Comment: I totally forgot about the REPLACE function lol.. nice and concise. one thing though.. I believe you have to cast it as a DECIMAL and not a FLOAT

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** this may not be a complete answer.. this is just going to show you how to convert your varchar 'number' into an actual decimal.

I'm not sure what exactly you need considering what you've given us.. but a way you can convert the data to a number is like this

**TEST WITH SAMPLE DATA MATCHING YOUR DECIMAL:**

```
SELECT CAST(testing as DECIMAL (10,2)) FROM(
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        CAST(left_side as UNSIGNED), '.' , CAST(right_side as UNSIGNED)
    ) as testing FROM(
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('0,5', ',', 1) as left_side,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('0,5', ',', -1) as right_side
) as t
) as final;
```

this will give you a decimal with 10 spaces on the left of the period and 2 spaces on the right of the period. now to convert to your query.

**PUTTING IT INTO YOUR QUERY:**

```
SELECT CAST(testing as DECIMAL (10,2)) 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(
            CAST(left_side as UNSIGNED), '.' , CAST(right_side as UNSIGNED)
        ) as testing 
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(charge, ',', 1) as left_side,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(charge, ',', -1) as right_side
        FROM detailsfiche 
        WHERE ref_hl = :ref_hl && intervenant = :intervenant
    ) as t
) as final;
```

I don't really have a way to test this but I believe itll do what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's syntax for delimiting the fractional part of a floating point number from the integer part always uses a dot. MySQL's localization doesn't allow commas, the national customs of the user notwithstanding.

For example, the value one-half is represented `0.5` and cannot be represented `0,5` even in Europe.